# Restrict usage/generate a compile error when someone uses a particular method in an Objective-C class/object

Tags: objective-c, overriding, subclass, pragma

Suppose I have an `AwesomeClass` but I cannot change it's implementation (ie it is from a static library or framework). I like everything about `AwesomeClass` except for `- (void)thatOneBadMethod`. I can subclass `AwesomeClass` to be `MyAwesomeClass` and override that method with an empty implementation (not calling `super`) but the problem is that if my fellow developer is using `MyAwesomeClass` and is unaware of my actions he may try to use `thatOneBadMethod` thinking that it is doing something it is not.

Is there some preprocessor directive that I can put in the override for `thatOneBadMethod` so that he gets a compiler error or warning when he tries to use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [deprecate](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#deprecated) the method in the header file:

```
-(void)thatOneBadMethod __attribute__ ((deprecated("Unsupported, please call 'thatOneGoodMethod' instead!")));
```

But I'd also suggest generating an error when people try to call it:

```
-(void)thatOneBadMethod {
  NSAssert(NO, @"Unsupported, please call 'thatOneGoodMethod' instead!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the both tips. I didn't think of the `NSAssert` route but I like the deprecated approach better.